# How to use PHP COM to invoke kernel32.GetTickCount?

Tags: php, windows, dll

I'm trying to execute GetTickCount from KERNEL32.DLL through PHP COM extension and had no success. What ProgID or Class ID should I use to execute GetTickCount?

```
$com = new COM("?WhatProgID.ID?");
$time = $com->GetTickCount();
```

in C++ it looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << GetTickCount() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DynamicWrapper:

1. Download `dynwrap.dll` http://techsupt.winbatch.com/techsupt/dynawrapNt.zip (or other version from here  [DynaWrap - DynaCall Wrapper](http://glsft.free.fr/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=47)):
2. Unpack and register: `regsvr32 dynwrap.dll /c` (you can also recompile it if you like)

Now this code below should work (it works for me):

```
$com = new COM("DynamicWrapper");
$com->Register("KERNEL32.DLL", "GetTickCount", "i=l", "f=s", "r=l");
echo $com->GetTickCount(0);
```

Description of the input parameters is in `Readme.txt`.